# Compound assignment to Python class and instance variables

Tags: python, class

I've been trying to understand Python's handling of class and instance variables. In particular, I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645/python-static-variable/69067#69067) quite helpful. Basically it says that if you declare a class variable, and then you do an assignment to `[instance].property`, you will be assigning to a different variable altogether -- one in a different namespace from the class variable.

So then I considered -- if I want every instance of my class to have a member with some default value (say zero), should I do it like this:

```
class Foo:
    num = 0
```

or like this?

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.num = 0
```

Based on what I'd read earlier, I'd think that the second example would be initializing the 'right' variable (the instance instead of the class variable). However, I find that the first method works perfectly well too:

```
class Foo:
    num = 0

bar = Foo()
bar.num += 1 # good, no error here, meaning that bar has an attribute 'num'
bar.num
>>> 1
Foo.num
>>> 0 # yet the class variable is not modified! so what 'num' did I add to just now?
```

So.. why does this work? What am I not getting? FWIW, my prior understanding of OOP has come from C++, so explanation by analogy (or pointing where it breaks down) might be useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Personally, I've found [these documents](http://www.cafepy.com/article/python_types_and_objects/python_types_and_objects.html) by Shalabh Chaturvedi extremely useful and informative regarding this subject matter.

`bar.num += 1` is a shorthand for `bar.num = bar.num + 1`. This is picking up the class variable `Foo.num` on the righthand side and assigning it to an instance variable `bar.num`.

Comment: And when I'm saying class / instance `variable` what I really mean is `attribute`.

Answer (score 2):

In the following code, `num` is a class member.

```
class Foo:
    num = 0
```

A C++ equivalent would be something like

```
struct Foo {
  static int num;
};

int Foo::num = 1;
```

---

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.num = 0
```

`self.num` is an instance member (`self` being an instance of `Foo`).

In C++, it would be something like

```
struct Foo {
  int num;
};
```

---

I believe that Python allows you to have a class member and an instance member sharing the same name (C++ doesn't). So when you do `bar = Foo()`, `bar` is an instance of `Foo`, so with `bar.num += 1`, you increment the instance member.

Comment: Your C++ equivalent appears to have incremented the value of num by 1! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
bar.num += 1
```

creates a new instance variable 'num' on the 'bar' instance because it doesn't yet exist (and then adds 1 to this value)

an example:

```
class Foo:
  def __init__(self):
    self.num= 1

bar = Foo()
print bar.num
```

this prints 1

```
print bar.foo
```

this gives an error as expected: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
AttributeError: Foo instance has no attribute 'foo'

```
bar.foo = 5
print bar.foo
```

now this prints 5

so what happens in your example: bar.num is resolved as Foo.num because there's only an class attribute. then foo.num is actually created because you assign a value to it.

Comment: uh... `bar.foo += 1` also gives an error, so clearly Python doesn't create instance variables whenever it encounters them in an expression containing '+='. My question is, how does creating class variables lead to the initialization of the corresponding instance variables?

Comment: @int3. This pertains to how attributes are resolved. When access an attribute, the object is searched first (`num` in this case), then the object's type (`Foo`) in this case, then the base classes of the object's type and their bases. If no matching attribute is found `AttributeError` is raised.

Comment: indeed, and then the instance variable is created because we assign a value to it. i'll update the example

Answer (score 0):

Searching for this very question, both this StackOverflow question and two (rather old, but valid) slides by Guido van Rossum ([1](http://www.python.org/doc/essays/ppt/acm-ws/sld051.htm), [2](http://www.python.org/doc/essays/ppt/acm-ws/sld052.htm)) came up high. Guido's slides state this behavior has to do with Python's search order for accessing the attribute (in the case of the example above `num`). Thought it'd be nice to put the two together right here :)

Answer (score -3):

I think you just found a bug in Python there. bar.num += 1 should be an error, instead, it is creating an attribute num in the object bar, distinct from Foo.num.

It's a really strange behavior.

Comment: @Morgaelyn: No this is not a bug, this is intended behaviour. Read up on python classes http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html

Comment: As MattH says, this intended and documented behavior. So, no, it's not a bug.

Comment: Now I have understood. b.num += 1 is the same as b.num = b.num + 1. The first b.num refers to the object attribute and is created. The second b.num refers actually to Foo.num and is 0. NOW that makes sense. I still uphold that this is a design error in the language. It's easy to assume that b.num in b.num += 1 refers always to the same variable, but it actually refers to two unrelated variables at the same time.

Comment: Not a design error.  It's an implementation detail.  You usually don't shadow a class attribute with an instance attribute.