# Iterative assignment of mutable-type default values for object attributes

Tags: python, python-3.x

My goal is to set default values of mutable type (list) for several object attributes. Per the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681243/how-should-i-declare-default-values-for-instance-variables-in-python), I set the default values of those attributes to `None` in the arguments of `__init__`, then I assign them the value `[]` in `__init__` if they took on their default value. Here's a representation of this:

```
class Wat(object):
    def __init__(self, arg1=None, arg2=None, arg3=None):
        for arg in arg1, arg2, arg3:
            if arg == None:
                arg = []
        self.arg1 = arg1
        self.arg2 = arg2
        self.arg3 = arg3

    def give(self, thing):
        self.arg1.append(thing)
        self.arg2.append(thing)
        self.arg3.append(thing)

wat = Wat()
wat.give(5)
```

However, this throws the following exception:

`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'`.

I don't see how `wat.arg1`, `wat.arg2`, and `wat.arg3` can still have type `None` at the time `wat.give(5)` is called -- they should have been reassigned to `[]` in `__init__`. It must have something to do with the way I coded the assignment, because this works:

```
class Wat(object):
    def __init__(self, arg1=None, arg2=None, arg3=None):
        if arg1 == None:
            arg1 = []
        if arg2 == None:
            arg2 = []
        if arg3 == None:
            arg3 = []
        self.arg1 = arg1
        self.arg2 = arg2
        self.arg3 = arg3

    def give(self, thing):
        self.arg1.append(thing)
        self.arg2.append(thing)
        self.arg3.append(thing)

wat = Wat()
wat.give(5)
```

To my mind, the two syntaxes are functionally equivalent, but you can imagine how the latter syntax becomes very tedious and aesthetically displeasing as the number of arguments assigned in this way increases.

What's wrong with the former syntax? How can I fix it? Thanks.

EDIT: Several of you have identified the problem, but I still don't have a satisfying solution. @roippi suggested an efficient method for assigning the variables one at a time, but suppose I have 100 of these variables. How do I do this assignment in the fewest lines of code? That was the original purpose of the loop. Thanks folks.

Comment: you can just do `self.arg1 = arg1 if arg1 else []`, etc.  Skip that intermediate step.

Comment: @roippi, consider `if arg1 is None else []`, otherwise the conditions are not the same.

Comment: @kroolik if your class has defined behavior over multiple falsy values, sure.  Otherwise I consider the distinction meaningless.

Comment: @roippi, in the other case, wouldn't `self.arg1 = arg1 or []` be simpler? ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for arg in arg1, arg2, arg3:
   if arg == None:
       arg = []
```

In this loop you're creating new references to the objects pointed by `arg1`, `arg2`, `arg3` and after checking their value against `None` you're assigning those variables(`arg`) to new object, so the older objects are still unchanged. So, it is roughly equivalent to:

```
>>> lis = [1, 2, 3]
>>> x = lis[0]  #now `x` points to lis[0]
>>> x = []      #now `x` points to a different object, this won't affect lis[0]
>>> lis
[1, 2, 3]
>>> x = lis[1]
>>> x = []
>>> lis
[1, 2, 3]
...
```

Note that it is better to use `arg is None` rather than `arg == None`.

Answer (score 2):

> EDIT: Several of you have identified the problem, but I still don't
>   have a satisfying solution. @roippi suggested an efficient method for
>   assigning the variables one at a time, but suppose I have 100 of these
>   variables. How do I do this assignment in the fewest lines of code?
>   That was the original purpose of the loop. Thanks folks.

Whenever someone asks this question, inevitably they're using the wrong data structure.

For example, you could be using the `**kwargs` method to capture *all* keyword arguments passed to your `Wat` object.  You can do what you want with them from there, treating `kwargs` as a normal `dict`.

```
class Wat(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.arg1 = kwargs.get('arg1', [])
        self.arg2 = kwargs.get('arg2', [])
        self.arg3 = kwargs.get('arg3', [])
```

or

```
class Wat(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.kwdict = kwargs
```

Or some combination of them:

```
class Wat(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.kwdict = kwargs
        self.kwdict['arg1'] = self.kwdict.get('arg1',[])
        self.kwdict['arg2'] = self.kwdict.get('arg2',[])
        self.kwdict['arg3'] = self.kwdict.get('arg3',[])
```

It doesn't even seem you care about the argument names, so you could just use `*args`:

```
class Wat(object):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.args = list(args)
        while len(self.args) < 3:
            self.args.append([])
```

etc.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are assigning the empty list to the loop variable, which changes on every iteration, i.e. `arg` is not the same variable as `arg1` yet they share the same reference at the beginning of the iteration.

Answer (score 1):

If all of your variables have this same behaviour, then you can use `setattr` to set attributes in loop, and `locals()` to access your values. I use `inspect` to get all variables names, you can hard code them, or evaluate, or get with any reasonable mean:

```
import inspect

class Wat(object):
    def __init__(self, arg1=None, arg2=None, arg3=None):
        arg_spec, _v, _k, _d = inspect.getargspec(self.__init__)
        for k in arg_spec[1:]:
            value = locals()[k]
            value = [] if value is None else value
            setattr(self, k, value)

    def give(self, thing):
        self.arg1.append(thing)
        self.arg2.append(thing)
        self.arg3.append(thing)

>>> wat = Wat(arg2=[1,2])
>>> wat.give(5)
>>> wat2 = Wat()
>>> wat2.give(6)
>>> wat.__dict__
{'arg1': [5], 'arg2': [1, 2, 5], 'arg3': [5]}
>>> wat2.__dict__
{'arg1': [6], 'arg2': [6], 'arg3': [6]}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
def default(x, fn):
    return fn() if x is None else x

class Wat(object):
    def __init__(self, arg1=None, arg2=None, arg3=None):
        self.arg1 = default(arg1, list)
        self.arg2 = default(arg2, list)
        self.arg3 = default(arg3, list)
```