# How to fix: AttributeError:Class object has no attribute

Tags: python, attributeerror

I am setting up a class, and as first step has used `__init__` function to initialize the attributes. However when I try to create an instance from that class, it shows the `AttributeError`.

I have checked the codes again and again to see if there is anything wrong with the syntax but the error remains

```
class RandomWalk():
    def ___init___(self, points = 10):
        """initialize attributes of a walk"""
        self.points = points
        self.x_values = [0]
        self.y_values = [0]

rw = RandomWalk()
print(rw.points)
```

I expect the output of 10 as default value of `points`, but instead the error shows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test1.py", line 10, in <module>
    print(rw.points)
AttributeError: 'RandomWalk' object has no attribute 'points'
```

The issue remains if I replace attribute `points` with either `x_values` or `y_values`

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681243/how-should-i-declare-default-values-for-instance-variables-in-python

Answer (score 5):

You have extra underscores in your constructor, so it is not being called. Use two on either side: `__init__`.